# Send Http Requests in Kotlin

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, http

So i had an App in Python now im trying to transfer it to Kotlin. I have a One Liner in Python and it Handles the Requests, after about 7 Hours i was not able to find a way to simply send requests and work with the response in Kotli, i would be gratefull if someone could give me an exapmle how to transfer this Python Code to Kotlin Thanks:

```
response = requests.get(BASE + "Login/1" , {"Name": Name , "Password": Password})
```

I sipmly send a request with 2 parameters attached and get Json as a response, thats all I need. The server itself is build with flask (Python)

```
    fun LoginServer(): Response<ResponseBody> {// Create Retrofit instance
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        // Create API client
        val apiClient = retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)

        print("kek")
        // Make the request
        val loginName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.loginName)
        val loginPasswort = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.loginPasswort)
        val response = apiClient.login(1, loginName.text.toString(), loginPasswort.text.toString());
        return response
}
```

this is the nearest I came to a solution however sadly it still did not work.

Comment: Are you set on using Retrofit or is the question more general as the title implies? Also, your sample code contains Android things, but you didn't specify if you were targeting Android or not -- I assumed you were and added the Android tag. Also, if you do want to use Retrofit, I'd recommend adding more details than "did not work" as to what specifically does not work e.g. error messages or other details.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, Yes i am targeting android, and no i am not set to use retrofit, it is just the only thing i found with some decent toutorials.